# SQL joining table

Tags: sql

I have this piece of code:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
JOIN productsInventory
WHERE sku = '$psku' AND sell_price = '$sell_price'
```

Where, there are two tables named `products` & `productsInventory` and `sku` & `sell_price` are their column names respectively. Is it the right way to write sql?

Comment: If you are using `JOIN` between two tables, then you need to specify the common column in `ON` condition like `ON products.id = productsInventory.product_id`

Comment: @Viki888 It depends on the DB and is not mandatory in every DB.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code isn't ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand how join works in sql. For that you can refer 
http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join. 
You should specify on which column you want to join two tables in on clause. 
In your code common column in `products` table and `productsInventory` table should be specified in on clause of join.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products AS l 
JOIN productsInventory AS r 
ON l.sku = r.sku
AND l.sell_price = r.sell_price;
```

Dpending on the sql dialect you are using that may vary.

Comment: Here, sku is a column from 'products' table, and sell_price is a column from 'productsInventory' table.

Comment: Well for a join you will need at least one column that the two tables can be joined by. So in your case that might be a product id as foreign key in the inventory table for example.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify with which columns you are joining the tables using the `ON` clause. In order to join tables, you usually need to have some column both tables have in common.

```
SELECT * FROM products 
JOIN productsInventory on products.<CommonColumn> = productsInventory.<CommonColumn>
WHERE sku = '$psku' AND sell_price = '$sell_price'
```